# Evaluating $\inf\left\{x+\frac{1}{x} : x>0\right\}$ without limits or derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

I want to evaluate

$$\inf\left\{x+\frac{1}{x} : x>0\right\}.$$

It is easy to do in a minute with derivatives but in my real analysis problem book this question is in the first chapter before limits or sequence and derivative.
So I am not sure what to use (I think just inequalities), without defining limits. I am not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe that, by the AM-GM inequality,

$$x+\frac{1}{x}\geq2\sqrt{x\cdot\frac{1}{x}}=2.$$

Furthermore we have equality when $x=1$. It follows that

$$\inf\left\{x+\frac{1}{x} : x>0\right\}=2.$$

Answer (score 5):

Since $x>0$, we have:
$$x+1/x=(\sqrt{x})^2+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2=\left(\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2+2\ge 2$$
Hence, $2$ is a lower bound of $x+1/x$ on $(0,+\infty)$. Since $2$ is attained when $x=1$, we have that $2$ is the minimum on $(0,+\infty)$ of $x+1/x$ and so $2$ is its infimum.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a funny solution. For $f(x)=x+x^{-1}$ we have $$f(x)^2=f(x^2)+2$$ Denoting $a=\inf f(x)$ gives $a^2=a+2,$ hence $a=2.
$